# Move checkbox label to left on bootstrap custom checkbox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a checkbox

```
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
   <input type="checkbox"  id="location"  v-model="checkedLocations"   value="location" name="customRadioInline1" class="custom-control-input">
   <label class="custom-control-label" for="location"> Option 1</label>
</div>
```

How do I move the label to display on the left? I have tried changing the order but it just breaks the checkbox functionlity.

```
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
         <label class="custom-control-label" for="location2"> Option 2</label>
        <input type="checkbox"  id="location2"  value="location2" name="custom2" class="custom-control-input">
   </div>
```

[CODEPEN Link to show both examples](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QzXqjW)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The checkbox is **not** the actual `<input>` (that's hidden). This is done in order to style it consistently cross-browser, cross-device, as that's not currently possible for `<input type="checkbox">`.

Instead, the `::before` pseudo-element of the `<label>` is used.

Therefore, you should place a custom class on the wrapper (`custom-control-right` in the example below) and add some CSS that overrides the default:

```css
div.custom-control-right {
  padding-right: 24px;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-left: 16px;
  margin-right: 0;
}
div.custom-control-right .custom-control-label::before,
div.custom-control-right .custom-control-label::after{
  right: -1.5rem;
  left: initial;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div style="margin:20px;">
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline custom-control-right">
        <input type="checkbox"  id="location"     value="location" name="custom1" class="custom-control-input">
       <label class="custom-control-label" for="location"> Option 1</label>
    </div>
  
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline custom-control-right">
         <input type="checkbox"  id="location2"  value="location2" name="custom2" class="custom-control-input">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="location2"> Option 2</label>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** you can replace `div.custom-control-right` selector with `.custom-control-right`, if this code is parsed **after** you load Bootstrap css. However, on SO, the linked resources are loaded after the code in CSS panel and I had to overqualify the selector in order for it to work.

Comment: My bad, I only tested it on the label text, not on the box. I updated with required selector.

Comment: There is a small space between the checkbox and the label that doesn't trigger a change. But that's intentional and it's how the original one works too. It's intended so that the label text can be selected without triggering a change on it. I decided to keep that. If you don't want it, you need to add some `padding-right` and an equally negative margin to the `<label>`, so it covers the checkbox.

Answer (score 12):

The answers don't seem to work with `custom-switch`. Here's a working example.

**CSS**

```
div.custom-control-right {
    padding-right: 24px;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}
div.custom-control-right .custom-control-label::after{
    right: -1.5rem;
    left: auto;
}
div.custom-control-right .custom-control-label::before {
    right: -2.35rem;
    left: auto;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="custom-control custom-control-right custom-switch">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" disabled id="customSwitch2">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch2">Right switch element</label>
</div>
```

**JsFiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/2cmbq9r0/

*Edit: changed `left:initial` to `left:auto` to make it work with IE11.*

Answer (score 1):

Try it: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/abhineetV/py7ghmte/2/)

```
<div style="margin:20px;">
  <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" id="location" value="location" name="custom1" class="custom-control-input">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="location"> Option 1</label>
  </div>

  <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">

    <input type="checkbox" id="location2" value="location2" name="custom2" class="custom-control-input">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="location2"> Option 2</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.custom-checkbox {
  padding-left: 0;
}

label.custom-control-label {
  padding-right: 1.5rem;
}

.custom-control-label::before,
.custom-control-label::after {
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
}
```

Comment: Note this will change all the `custom-checkbox` instances. Note there are specific classes for specific cases (i.e.: `custom-control-inline`). The best approach is to leave the default functionality untouched, so it still works as intended and add new functionality using a custom class, so you can apply it where needed.

Comment: You can create a new class and put the above CSS in it. so that you can use it if needed. example: https://jsfiddle.net/abhineetV/mhrgvkbj/3/